# MacBook Pro never goes to sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, power

I got a brand new mid-2015 MacBook Pro 15", OSX 10.11.3.

Display never turns off even it is configured to turn off after 10 mins in power adapter AND in battery mode. Screen saver (aerial) stays active forever. I tried disconnecting all USB peripherals connected - it did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any apps running? I have one that will keep the machine awake forever if it's running

Comment: yea some apps running, I will try a fresh restart and see if it happens too

Answer (score 1):

Back when the Aerial screen saver was first released there was a bug that would prevent Macs from going to sleep. The developer fixed that bug a while ago. If this is still an issue for anyone they should try download the latest version of the screen saver from the following link.

https://github.com/JohnCoates/Aerial/releases

For those that are curious. The screen saver was originally written to use [AVPlayerView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerview) which by design keeps Macs awake when its playing a video. Aerial's developer rewrote the screen saver to use [AVPlayerLayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayerlayer) instead, which does allow Macs to sleep when they are playing video but otherwise idle.

Answer (score 1):

Look, it returns the terminal command:

```
pmset -g assertions
```